# Implement substr & strrchr in a loop

Tags: php

I have a while loop :

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $name = $row['a'].'|'.$row['b'].'|'.$row['c'].'|'.$row['d'];
        array_push($data, $name);
    }
    mysqli_close($db->con);
    echo json_encode($data);exit;
```

on $row['a'] I want to implement the following code :

```
<?php 
                $a= isset($row['a']) ? $row['a'] : '';
                $b= substr(strrchr($a, ":"), 1);
                ?>
```

expected output of while loop is as follows :

a1:a2:a3:a4, b, c, d
with subsrt & strrchr, it should be as follows :
a4, b, c, d

when I run the substr strrchr code on an isset $item(a) AFTER the loop returns results, it returns a4, but I need it to run during the loop.  Basically I am calling data to a table that appears as a1:a2:a3:a4 from my loop, but I only want it to say a4.
Is there a way to do this within the loop, so that I could echo the return of each $b ?

Comment: If you fetch the data ever row should have a `$row["a"]` ?!

Comment: sorry, that should be $row

Comment: @Rizier123 yes, indicative of say, a product #

Comment: What are you trying to do by  $b= substr(strrchr($a, ":"), 1);?

Comment: @MdeLorimier $b would get the correct value of $a, which is in the loop, I figure if I can insert $b in the place of $a in the loop, I would get my desired result

Comment: Can you provide detail on the context that make the two blocks of code related?

Comment: @MdeLorimier Added a more in depth explanation to answer